# How can I create an iOS Shortcut to email a photo?

Tags: iphone, ios, shortcuts-app

I want to be able to quickly send a photo to myself using a shortcut. I can create the shortcut and make it available via the share icon, but the Siri-suggested building block of sending it to myself doesn't include the photo in the email that gets sent. If I try to use the "Send Email" building block, I'm told I have to sign in to an email account to use it with Shortcuts. My login credentials, however, get rejected with "No valid server found", even though I can email manually from my phone without any trouble using the same credentials. Help?

Comment: please post your shortcut as screenshots and link too for those you wish to edit it.

Comment: I've posted the image at https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Rc-55vOIqleov2S9PdL10oj6vA9dD7ad.

Comment: why don't you use the get/ select image functionality of photos? Also, is it a work/school mail account? That can be a bit problematic I guess if there is no server settings page.

Comment: My primary use case is to be looking at a photo and want to email it to myself (via the share icon>shortcuts). I don't want to use the Select Photos action, because the photo I'm looking at is the one I want to send, i.e., the photo has already been implicitly selected. My email account is my personal account at TigerTech.net.